# Potential cause for ExecuteReaderAsync to lose context

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I've done a little abstraction on top of our data access layer, to abstract away whether we're using ole, mssql or others.

Oddly enough the following case works fine in the unit test with the exact same parameters but fails when called from our mvc application.

The code in question is this:

```
    public override Task<IDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var sqlCommand = _inner as SqlCommand;
        if (sqlCommand != null)
        {
            // always here because of implementation
            return sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken).ContinueWith(d => d.Result as IDataReader, cancellationToken);
        }

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _inner.ExecuteReader(), cancellationToken);
    }
```

Once i replace the call in the DAL with this:

```
    public override IDataReader ExecuteReader()
    {
        return _inner.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

everything works just as expected. Thus i conclude that the root of the problem should be somewhere in the implementation of my first code snippet.

Does anyone have an idea why this implementation works just fine in a unit test but fails when called in a different context (despite exact same parameters)?

**Am i doing my casting to IDataReader incorrect? 
Once ExecuteReaderAsync is called the debugger just won't return.**

However prior to the reader there are other async calls which don't make the debugger to drop its' context, so it should not be surrounding call hierarchy causing the issue.

Update: Full code of AbstractDbCommandMssql:

```
internal class AbstractDbCommandMssql : AbstractDbCommand 
{
    protected override void OnDispose()
    {
        _inner.Dispose();
    }

    protected override IDbCommand GetUnderlyingCommand()
    {
        return _inner;
    }

    private readonly DataAccessMode _mode;

    private readonly IDbCommand _inner;

    public override IDbCommand Native
    {
        get { return _inner; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// NICHT manuell aufrufen!
    /// </summary>
    public AbstractDbCommandMssql()
    {
        _inner = new SqlCommand();
    }

    public override IDbDataParameter AddParameter<T>(ColumnType dataType, string name, T value, ParameterDirection direction = ParameterDirection.Input)
    {
        var paramValue = EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value) ? (object)DBNull.Value : value;

        var parameter = CreateParameter(dataType, name, direction);
        parameter.Value = paramValue;

        if (dataType == ColumnType.IntIdCache)
        {
            var castedValues = value as IEnumerable<int>;
            if(castedValues == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("The IntIdCache parameter requires the value to be IEnumerable<int>. Currently is: {0}", typeof(T)));

            var sqlParam = parameter as SqlParameter;
            if(sqlParam == null)
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Invalid type for parameter: \"{0}\".", parameter.GetType()));
            sqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            sqlParam.TypeName = "dbo.IntIdCache";

            ((SqlCommand) _inner).Parameters.AddWithValue(name, castedValues.ToIntIdCacheDataTable());
        }
        else
        {
            _inner.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }

        return parameter;
    }

    public override void Prepare()
    {
        _inner.Prepare();
    }

    public override void Cancel()
    {
        _inner.Cancel();
    }

    public override IDbDataParameter CreateParameter()
    {
        return new SqlParameter();
    }

    public override IDbDataParameter CreateParameter(ColumnType dataType, string name, ParameterDirection direction)
    {
        SqlDbType targetType;

        switch (dataType)
        {
            case ColumnType.Int:
                targetType = SqlDbType.Int;
                break;
            case ColumnType.Double:
                targetType = SqlDbType.Float;
                break;
            case ColumnType.DateTime:
                targetType = SqlDbType.DateTime2;
                break;
            case ColumnType.DateTimeSmall:
                targetType = SqlDbType.SmallDateTime;
                break;
            case ColumnType.Bool:
                targetType = SqlDbType.Bit;
                break;
            case ColumnType.Guid:
                targetType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier;
                break;
            case ColumnType.String:
                targetType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
                break;
            case ColumnType.IntIdCache:
                targetType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                break;
            case ColumnType.Enum:
                targetType = SqlDbType.Int;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dataType", dataType, string.Format("{0} has been passed.", dataType.ToString()));
        }

        return new SqlParameter(name, targetType){ Direction = direction};
    }

    public override int ExecuteNonQuery()
    {
        return _inner.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public override IDataReader ExecuteReader()
    {
        return _inner.ExecuteReader();
    }

    public override IDataReader ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
    {
        return _inner.ExecuteReader(behavior);
    }

    public override Task<IDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var sqlCommand = _inner as SqlCommand;
        if (sqlCommand != null)
        {
            return sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken).ContinueWith(d => d.Result as IDataReader, cancellationToken);
        }

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _inner.ExecuteReader(), cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task<IDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var sqlCommand = _inner as SqlCommand;
        if (sqlCommand != null)
            return sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(behavior, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(d => d.Result as IDataReader, cancellationToken);

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _inner.ExecuteReader(behavior), cancellationToken);
    }

    public override object ExecuteScalar()
    {
        return _inner.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    public override IDbConnection Connection
    {
        get { return _inner.Connection; }
        set { _inner.Connection = value; }
    }

    public override IDbTransaction Transaction
    {
        get { return _inner.Transaction; }
        set { _inner.Transaction = value; }
    }

    public override string CommandText
    {
        get { return _inner.CommandText; }
        set { _inner.CommandText = value; }
    }

    public override int CommandTimeout
    {
        get { return _inner.CommandTimeout; }
        set { _inner.CommandTimeout = value; }
    }

    public override CommandType CommandType
    {
        get { return _inner.CommandType; }
        set { _inner.CommandType = value; }
    }

    public override IDataParameterCollection Parameters
    {
        get { return _inner.Parameters; }
    }

    public override UpdateRowSource UpdatedRowSource
    {
        get { return _inner.UpdatedRowSource; }
        set { _inner.UpdatedRowSource = value; }
    }
}
```

Code which calls the methods in question:

```
            using (connectionInstance = CreateConnection())
            {
// debugger steps past this line with no issues at all.
                await connectionInstance.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);

                using (command)
                {
                    command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
                    command.Connection = connectionInstance.Native;
// this works for unit tests but loses context in mvc. any idea why?
//                      using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken))
// this works from mvc + unit tests
                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
... processing code
```

Update 2:

[image: State before calling the ExecuteReaderAsync]
[image: Thread paused - position it's currently waiting at]
[image: Thread paused - state of previous thread]

Update 3:

Unit test calls which works just fine:
[image: Unit test calls, which both work fine]

Mvc call which fails:

```
    private List<UpcomingAppointment> LoadUpcomingAppointments(int projectStructureId, IEnumerable<int> serviceProgramIds, DateTime startDate, TimeSpan previewTime, bool showInRange = true, bool showWithOverrung = true)
    {
        var provider = IoC.Instance.GetInstance<IUpcomingAppointmentsProvider>();
        var endDate = startDate.Add(previewTime);

        var task = provider.GetAppointmentsAsync(this.GetSessionCache().ParallelDataAccessor, projectStructureId, serviceProgramIds, showInRange, showWithOverrung, startDate, endDate);

        return task.Result;
    }
```

Comment: You definitely need to show more code. I.e. `_inner` seem to be field of some sort (or even property), do you ever change it later? Exception with call stack would help too.

Comment: Consider adding note in the post that you are aware of ["don't create async wrappers for synchronous methods"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) to avoid extra comments/discussions.

Comment: added more code for clarification. While i was not aware of that blog post (which seems worth a read no matter this issue), i am at no point calling a wrapped synchronus method, which is why this issue is puzzling me so much. I've had debugger context loses before, but those were resolved by fixing missing await calls. Oddly enough getting past the first async method call works just fine. Code updates will explain it in an easier fashion

Comment: Override the Begin/End methods as well. Make them `throw new NotImplementedEx();`. I have a hunch that these methods are being called. They delegate to your `override IDataReader ExecuteReader`.

Comment: @usr No. override IDataReader ExecuteReader is not being called unless i replace the entire call. The problem should be related to the code in my first snippet

Comment: What do you mean by "loses context"?

Comment: @usr the debugger no longer returns after pressing F10 when attempting to step past the call of ExecuteReaderAsync. Usually this happens when you're releasing a thread when using tasks without awaiting their result, which isn't the case here.

Comment: `abstract away whether we're using ole, mssql or others` Like, um, `IDbCommand` and friends? I mean, why do this since the abstraction layer already exists?

Comment: The usage of `ContinueWith`, `Result`, and `StartNew` are not ideal (especially in an MVC app), but they shouldn't cause this kind of problem. Details: `ContinueWith` should use an explicit scheduler; `Result` will wrap any exceptions in an extra `AggregateException`; `StartNew` will negatively impact scalability and changes the semantics of the cancellation token.

Comment: So what does the app do when the debugger in unable to follow? Does it do nothing? Does it run? Pause the debugger after a few seconds. Is there a thread that has your code on the stack? A wait? A deadlock?

Comment: If you need a little abstraction, a MicroORM like Dapper would be better. You can even use it as starting point, [the code](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper%20NET45/SqlMapperAsync.cs)  is about 800 lines, including code for mapping types and caching commands.

Comment: @StephenCleary why? does IDbCommand allow me to generate entities from statements no matter the underlying db driver? No it does not. why even post a comment with the pure intent of mockery for no reason?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos While i've looked into Dapper for personal projects (since it seems to be the fastest there is) i can't use it for this sadly. I need to be able to be able to synchronize entities between multiple application domains and many other things, which are easier to do if you don't have to read up on another package. Good suggestion though

Comment: @AndreasMüller you've already spent more time than you would need to use Dapper, perhaps even steal its mapper and caching. As for synchronization and domains - they have no effect. It really is *micro*, there is no context, just command execution and mapping to result objects or even `dynamic`

Comment: @usr Appears to do nothing. Seems to run (does not disappear from threads window. Pause -> Yes, still on the stack, waiting for result. Deadlock? - unlikely because it works just fine with ExecuteReader() and i am not doing any locking. I've done both await + .Result to get my result, but oddly enough the .Result version only fails in mvc. Really weird.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes i did. However i also need batch inserts and updated properties for inserts/updates. Last time i checked dapper seemed to be a readonly micro ORM? Also this problem isn't really a show stopper. i don't care that much about using ExecuteReader instead, since that makes it work just fine. I'm just curious what could be the cause of this to fail in some cases but work in others (unit test)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok - dapper isn't readonly. But i can't tell for sure wether its multi inserts use adapters to do the inserting (which is mandatory, because our FK make an insert rather slow). Property updates are also mandatory. That's why i made the decision anyway - However i am still more curious about why the problem is happening than thinking about an alternative because of this one problem.

Comment: @AndreasMüller it isn't read-only. It has both Query(Async) and Execute(Async) functionality. It also allows multiple executions of a single command for multiple parameters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was afraid i made the wrong call there but i checked https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper%20NET45/SqlMapperAsync.cs (which frankly i should have checked first) and there is indeed no use of adapters + property updates on insert/update

Comment: Result deadlocking is expected and ExecuteReader not deadlocking is also expected. I'll explain later. So are you calling Result or Wait somewhere here? If yes, post that code. Also, post the callstack where you found threads waiting (maybe as an image).

Comment: @usr added screenshots. They seem small though. Uploaded through SO.

Comment: @AndreasMüller: I wasn't mocking. I have seen other devs write an entire abstraction layer over `IDbCommand` without adding *any* functionality. Sometimes abstraction is added out of habit rather than necessity.

Comment: @StephenCleary Ok, it sounded like it. Nevermind then. And yes, it is something which happens. I spend enough time on thedailywtf and other sites to inform myself about antipattern/behaviors to avoid that though - which isn't the case for everyone to be fair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a case of the classic [ASP.NET deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Don't do [sync over async](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx). If you must do it use a safe workaround for the deadlock such as:

```
Task.Run(() => SomethingAsync()).Result
```

Note, that this is not helpful to efficiency but it's not a major issue if this piece of code isn't too hot.

Comment: Verifying this. Sounds promising and would explain why it works just fine in unit tests. Thanks for the links+effort. upvote+check will follow probably

Comment: This indeed fixed my issue. Funny how OpenAsync on the connection didn't run into the same issue. Also explains why this worked with no issue on a async controller action, since the underlying controller factory delivers a different environment which seems to make issues like this not happen at all.

Comment: The deadlock happens if you wait on something that posts to the sync context which await does by default. Library code usually doesn't do that. Your own data access "library" should probably use ConfigureAwait(false) everywhere.

Comment: changing it in this place fixed the issue without changing any consumer code (the code you put as answer). Thanks! And it all makes perfect sense.